# How to include a library in the path while compiling?

Tags: compilation, go

I'm reading [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/Rj5t1h_ztxI/Fgs6HfLqMHAJ) post about go and  was trying to compile the source code found [here](http://code.google.com/p/rsc/source/detail?r=70443b1ae03926b24920266383fad4ec6c9a2ce7)

I downloaded the source code, compiled the first file with `make` and I can see the object is generated:

```
$pwd
/Users/oscarryz/code/go/rsc/rosetta/graph

$ls -ltR
total 136
-rw-r--r--  1 oscarryz  staff  61295 Sep 17 16:20 _go_.6
drwxr-xr-x  3 oscarryz  staff    102 Sep 17 16:20 _obj
-rw-r--r--  1 oscarryz  staff    126 Sep 17 16:17 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 oscarryz  staff   2791 Sep 17 16:17 graph.go

./_obj:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 oscarryz  staff  102 Sep 17 16:20 rsc.googlecode.com

./_obj/rsc.googlecode.com:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 oscarryz  staff  102 Sep 17 16:20 hg

./_obj/rsc.googlecode.com/hg:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 oscarryz  staff  102 Sep 17 16:20 rosetta

./_obj/rsc.googlecode.com/hg/rosetta:
total 136
-rw-r--r--  1 oscarryz  staff  68486 Sep 17 16:20 graph.a
```

No my question is, how do I refer to that compiled code from the maze directory:

```
/Users/oscarryz/code/go/rsc/rosetta/maze/maze.go
```

Whose import declarations are:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "rand"
    "time"

    "rsc.googlecode.com/hg/rosetta/graph"
)
```

And right now is failing to compile with the error message:

```
6g  -o _go_.6 maze.go 
maze.go:20: can't find import: rsc.googlecode.com/hg/rosetta/graph
make: *** [_go_.6] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it, wasn't that hard.

> 6g flags: -I DIR search for packages in DIR

I have to specify the `-I` option like this:

```
6g -I ../graph/_obj/ -o _go_.6 maze.go
```

Comment: note to my self, to link it I needed `-L` option as in: `6l -L ../graph/ -o maze _go_.6`